# How to evaluate new instance in js file while working with vue js framework?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

usually when i am working with java script i used eval when i want to call function or create new instance dynamically so if i have a specific class or object called new ActivityNode for example and have its name stored in a string

```
var nodeType="ActivityNode";
```

i can create an instance using eval like this

```
var node =eval("new "+ nodeType +"()");
```

and its work

but since i start working with vue js framework the eval() cant find the Activity node

so i can create a new instance when i type

```
let node=new ActivityNode();
```

but if i tried using eval() to create it

```
   let node =eval("new ActivityNode()");
```

i got an error: Activity node is not defined

how can i fix that and make eval() working?